# XmlSerializer: Deserialize into XMLElement

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML:

```
<A>
    <B>hello</B>
    <C>bye</C>
    <D>
        <E>111</E>
        <F>222</F>
    </D>
</A>
```

And this class

```
[XmlRoot("A")]
public class A
{
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public System.Xml.XmlElement D { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, **I'm not interested in modeling "D" as a class.**

I'm deserializing this way:

```
string xml = "<A><B>hello</B><C>bye</C><D><E>111</E><F>222</F></D></A>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(A));

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    A a = (A)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    Console.WriteLine(a.D.OuterXml); // <-------
}
```

My current console output is this:

```
<E>111</E>
```

...which is a weird behavior, because `<D>` has two items inside, but the deserializer is only saving the first

**Question: What should I do to get this console output?**

```
<E>111</E><F>222</F>
```

Comment: What is `XMLElement` ?

Comment: sorry, XmlElement. I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply an `XmlAnyElement` attribute to property `D`.

It's inner Xml will contain `<E>111</E><F>222</F>`.
*`<E>111</E><F>222</F>` is not valid as an `OuterXml` as it lacks a root element.*

```
[XmlRoot("A")]
public class A
{
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement()]
    public XmlElement D { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Curious, what was the result without?

Comment: @sport, I cannot spot any difference if using or not the "D" parameter in attribute.
Have a look at [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zM6mDA).
But maybe I'm doing something wrong, since it seems it deserializes a <D>...</D> node to a `SomethingElse` Property (for A2 an A3 class in my example)

Comment: Ok to be honest the examples with letters in my post aren't the reality. Its a large XML with many tags and the result without specifying the element name was that it was mapping another element... weird.

Comment: I see, that's because `XmlAnyElement` maps ANY element. Like you say, the sample above shows only a part; by using `XmlAnyElement("D")` you ensure that only `<D>` gets mapped and not any other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XmlAnyElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute on `D`:

```
[XmlAnyElement]
public XmlElement D { get; set; }
```

> Specifies that the member (a field that returns an array of XmlElement or XmlNode objects) contains objects that represent any XML element that has no corresponding member in the object being serialized or deserialized.